# Form passing null value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have fixed my form load problem. I changed it to where the main menu wasn't being called on load event and that  fixed the issue. Now my retrieve event gets the version but never passes it to my form.

Here is my code for transferring process:

Where the information is being pulled from:

```
public string VersionPass { get; set; }
VersionPass = rtxtBoxNewVersion.Text;
```

This is the main menu where the value will be stored till they click the assign button. This is where it gets the value from the form.

```
public string VersionNum { get; set; }
VersionEditor newV = new VersionEditor();
newV.ShowDialog();

VersionNum = newV.VersionPass;

newV.Dispose();
```

Form being transferred to I am using form load because the value will not change: It never get the value into the PassedVersion = passedVersion.VersionNum; field.

```
MainMenu passedVersion = new MainMenu()
string PassedVersion;

private void Notification_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PassedVersion = passedVersion.VersionNum;
    rTxtBoxVersion.Text = PassedVersion;
}
```

Comment: Is the default property value for `Enabled` `false` on the form you are calling, or is it set to `false` in its constructor?

Comment: @gunr2171 It was set to false yes as default so I changed it to true. Then it only reloaded the main menu.

Comment: Please stick to code conventions and give your vars appropriate names. The load-event is sometimes tricky. It's never a good idea to handle other controls or show new forms in this event.

Comment: @user1567896 would you have an example of how to better handle it so I can learn from it?

Comment: Acutally I'm not not even sure what you are trying to do :). So it is difficult to give you an example.

Comment: @user1567896 alright I am creating a value in the top code form. that value needs to be passed to another form to be displayed. I use that top method to make the data public so i can access it. Well I have to pass the value to my menu first before It can go to my notification class. that is the second part. last part is where i try to set the value in my textbox on my form.

Comment: What is MainMenu? And why are you creating it in "Load"?

Comment: @noelicus mainmenu is where the start of my program is. That contains the buttons the bring you to the version class and notification class.

Comment: OK. Thought so! ... if define a `new` one then you are creating a whole new `MainMenu` dialog (object) while you are loading the notification one. That's gonna do bad things

Comment: @noelicus I was just looking at that. I am posting my corrections tell me if I am on or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to guess a bit here, but ...

1) Take out new `MainMenu()` from the `Notification_Load` call. This is probably stopping the dialog being created properly.

2) If you want to share information you either need to pass it to the new object, for example when you create it:

```
MyObject = new MyClass(SomeObjectToTellItAbout); 
// or maybe like this:
MyObject.InterestingInfo = SomeOtherObject;
```

If it's truely global information (app version, for example) you could make the info to share static (and then access it like this: `MainMenu.MyAppVersion`).

**Edit** based on comments:

You want to get an understanding of classes vs objects. A class is just a design; it's a concept. For example "human". An object is an *instantiation* of that class/concept/design, for example me. And you (another object). I can't find your name by saying `h = new human(); h.name()` and nor can you find your version by making a new MainMenu and asking it what version it is! Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I did that on my edit. It gets the data in the second set of code but stops there.

Comment: Best course of action from here is to create a test app showing your problem (i.e. minimum code possible) and paste that into your question. It's a bit hard to guess what's wrong here.

Comment: Exactly which line does it "stop" on?

Comment: It doesn't stop it just passes a null value. Let me update real quick.

Comment: Ok the edit has been put up. I used breakpoint to find if the VersionNum value was getting a value and it is but I it wont give a value to my notification form.

Comment: Of you've passed it to your notification form then you shouldn't be creating a new mainform...is that what you're doing?

Comment: That's the way I was taught to reference things. I was unsure of how to call it to the form for use. Still pretty new to this. Have an example of what to do I do better with visuals.

Comment: Check over my answer again :it explains what other options you have that will work. Good luck!

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting these to work..                  MyObject = new MyClass(SomeObjectToTellItAbout); 
// or maybe like this:
MyObject.InterestingInfo = SomeOtherObject;

Comment: I did VersionData = new MainMenu(I don't know what to use here) and I tried VersionData.(what goes here)? = (Not sure maybe a textbox)

Comment: Just make it static then. static string version. reference by MainMenu.version.

Comment: Thanks I'm still a little slow I realize now what you were saying. Thank you for all your help I really appreciate it.